# Date Changed After Form Submit in bsDatepicker

Tags: angular, date, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

> Date Format Changed from Y-m-d to Wed Sep 07 2005 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)

```
    when Page Loads default date 2005-09-01 00:00:00 is loaded , now if i want to change date from date picker to 2010-01-10 then after form submit date changed to  Wed Sep 07 2005 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But i need date format Y-m-d so that server side Php understand Date and save date in database.

Solution i tried

> DatePipe

```
 https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#description

 const now = Date.now();
const bsValue = this.datePipe.transform(now, 'short');
console.log(bsValue);
```

its convert date format correctly.

but after form submit date gets changed.

Date component code

```
                    import { Component, Input , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                    import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

                    import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
                    import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
                    @Component({
                      selector: 'date',
                      template: `
                          <div [formGroup]="form" >



                              <input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode-field"
                                bsDatepicker
                                [minDate]="minDate"
                                [maxDate]="maxDate"
                                [formControlName]="field.code"
                                [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig"
                                value="{{ field.value }}"/>
                              <span class="view-mode-field">{{ field.value }}</span>

                          </div>
                        `
                    })
                    export class DateComponent implements OnInit {
                      @Input() field: any = {};
                      @Input() form: FormGroup;
                      @Input() type: string;
                    bsInlineValue = new Date();

                      datePickerConfig = {
                        isAnimated: true,
                        containerClass: 'theme-blue',
                        showWeekNumbers: false,
                        dateInputFormat : 'YYYY-MM-DD' ,
                      };

                      minDate = new Date();
                      maxDate = new Date();

                      constructor( private datePipe: DatePipe , private bsDatepickerConfig: BsDatepickerModule) {
                        // This is just for tests.
                        // this.bsDatepickerConfig.dateInputFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
                        this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 36135); // 99 years
                        this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 7);
                      }

                      ngOnInit() {
                        // const ddMMyyyy = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"dd-MM-yyyy");
                        // console.log(ddMMyyyy); //output - 14-02-2019

                        const now = Date.now();
                        const bsValue = this.datePipe.transform(now, 'short');
                        console.log(bsValue);


                      }

                    }
```

Interface Date

```
            interface Date {
                /** Returns a string representation of a date. The format of the string depends on the locale. */
                toString(): string;
                /** Returns a date as a string value. */
                toDateString(): string;
                /** Returns a time as a string value. */
                toTimeString(): string;
                /** Returns a value as a string value appropriate to the host environment's current locale. */
                toLocaleString(): string;
                /** Returns a date as a string value appropriate to the host environment's current locale. */
                toLocaleDateString(): string;
                /** Returns a time as a string value appropriate to the host environment's current locale. */
                toLocaleTimeString(): string;
                /** Returns the stored time value in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. */
                valueOf(): number;
                /** Gets the time value in milliseconds. */
                getTime(): number;
                /** Gets the year, using local time. */
                getFullYear(): number;
                /** Gets the year using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCFullYear(): number;
                /** Gets the month, using local time. */
                getMonth(): number;
                /** Gets the month of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCMonth(): number;
                /** Gets the day-of-the-month, using local time. */
                getDate(): number;
                /** Gets the day-of-the-month, using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCDate(): number;
                /** Gets the day of the week, using local time. */
                getDay(): number;
                /** Gets the day of the week using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCDay(): number;
                /** Gets the hours in a date, using local time. */
                getHours(): number;
                /** Gets the hours value in a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCHours(): number;
                /** Gets the minutes of a Date object, using local time. */
                getMinutes(): number;
                /** Gets the minutes of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCMinutes(): number;
                /** Gets the seconds of a Date object, using local time. */
                getSeconds(): number;
                /** Gets the seconds of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCSeconds(): number;
                /** Gets the milliseconds of a Date, using local time. */
                getMilliseconds(): number;
                /** Gets the milliseconds of a Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getUTCMilliseconds(): number;
                /** Gets the difference in minutes between the time on the local computer and Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). */
                getTimezoneOffset(): number;
                /**
                  * Sets the date and time value in the Date object.
                  * @param time A numeric value representing the number of elapsed milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 GMT.
                  */
                setTime(time: number): number;
                /**
                  * Sets the milliseconds value in the Date object using local time.
                  * @param ms A numeric value equal to the millisecond value.
                  */
                setMilliseconds(ms: number): number;
                /**
                  * Sets the milliseconds value in the Date object using Universal Coordinated Time (UTC).
                  * @param ms A numeric value equal to the millisecond value.
                  */
                setUTCMilliseconds(ms: number): number;
```

Im using https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

- any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: can you provide a working example in stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

The Date change is due to the time zone difference between your frontend and the backend

Solution:
 - Before sending the date to the backend try to change it to the time zone of your backend server
 - When you display your date on the frontend you have to convert it back to the browser local timezone

Ps:Your can also use moment.js to parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates